# How to implement a Photoshop Curves editor in UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, bezier

I'm familiar with UIBezierPath and the corresponding CG routines, but none of them appear to draw the same type of path as what I see in Photoshop, etc.

How would one go about this? I'm just talking about the UI--letting the user drag around points.

[image: Five point curve example]

A java example I found is here: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/natcubic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into CGContextAddCurveToPoint and drag around  curve's control points. If you require more control points to create a complex curve, just split a resulting curve into simple segments.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx) It explains how to calculate the control points based on knots you have on your curve.

Comment: I guess my main issue was where to place the control points. They're not the actual points as shown, as those are endpoints.

Comment: Well here is a simple Mac app example which I think you can get the idea from: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/coregraphics-curves-and-lines-sample.html

Comment: Thanks. I'd checked that out a few days ago...still couldn't understand how to place control points in order to get the same kind of curvature.