# how to compute the control points for a smooth path given a set of points?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics, bezier

I am using UIBezierPath, but this question concerns control points for the paths, not the drawing. Given a set of points, I can render a path. However, I have not been able to figure out how to calculate the control points to have a smooth line like in a photo curves editor ( [How to implement a Photoshop Curves editor in UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013717/how-to-implement-a-photoshop-curves-editor-in-uikit) ).

The closest answer I've seen is here: [how can i trace the finger movement on touch for drawing smooth curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052119/how-can-i-trace-the-finger-movement-on-touch-for-drawing-smooth-curves)

However, I still cannot grasp the proper calculation. To sum it up in code:

```
for (int i = 0; i< points; i++) 
{
     ...

     [path addQuadCurveToPoint:nextPoint controlPoint:WTF];
}
```

Comment: The silence is so loud it hurts.

Comment: Do you want the curve to exactly pass through each of your given points?  Or do you want a smoother curve may just pass close to some of the given points?

Comment: @robmayoff I suppose close is good enough if it's a much simpler operation.

Comment: If it helps, most tone curves tend to operate with values interpolated using a spline curve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The image you linked to is an example that doesn't use quadratic curves, so I'm going to run 
with the image and not the code.

A bezier path on ios (and os x) underneath is basically a list of drawing commands and points. eg:

```
[path moveTo:CGMakePoint(1,1)];
[path curveToPoint:(10,10) controPoint1:(3,7) controlPoint2:(4,1)];
[path curveToPoint:(10,10) controPoint1:(15,17) controlPoint2:(21,11)];
[path closePath];
```

Results in:

```
moveto (1,1)      
curveto (10,10) (3,7) (4,1) 
curveto (20,0) (15,17) (21,11)    
closepath
```

Control points on a bezier path control the direction and rate of curve out of a point. The first control point(cp) controls the direction and rate of curve exiting the previous point and the second cp controls the same for the point you're curving to.  For a quadratic curve (what you get using addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint: ), both of these points are the same, as you can see in the docs for the method [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Getting a smooth curve along a set of points involves making cp1 and cp2 be colinear with each other and that line be parallel to the points at either end of that segment.

[image: Annotated curve]

This would look something like:

```
[path moveTo:2];
[path curveTo:3 controlPoint1:cp1 controlPoint2:cp2];
```

cp1 and cp2 can be computed by choosing some constant line length and doing some geometry (i forget all my line equations right now but they're [easily googleable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html)  )

Going to use #-># to designate a segment and #->#(cp#) to designate a control point for that segment's curveto call.

The next issue is making the curve smooth from the 2->3 segment going into 3->4 segment. At this point in your code, you should have a control point calculated for 2->3(cp2).  Given your constant line length from before (this will control how sharp of a curve you get), you can calculate a cp1 for 3->4 by getting a point colinear with 2->3(cp2) and point 3 in the diagram.  Then calculate a 3->4(cp2) that's colinear with 3->4(cp1) and parallel to the line that point 3 and point 4 form.  Rinse and repeat through your points array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, after reading through the links I am still unable to determine the right method. I blame my brain.

Comment: There is no way you write code for computing the control points.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but I had to do something similar to implement a curved path for notes to follow in this app, (www.app.net/hereboy).  Essentially, it is a path with three curves.

To do this I created 4 points per curve, a starting point, an ending point, and two control points at the 25% mark and the 75% mark.

Here is the code that I wrote to do this:

```
//create points along the keypath for curve.
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
const int TOTAL_POINTS = 3;
int horizontalWiggle = 15;

int stepChangeX = (endPoint.x - viewOrigin.x) / TOTAL_POINTS;
int stepChangeY = (endPoint.y - viewOrigin.y) / TOTAL_POINTS;

for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_POINTS; i++) {
    int startX = (int)(viewOrigin.x + i * stepChangeX);
    int startY = (int)(viewOrigin.y + i * stepChangeY);

    int endX = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+1) * stepChangeX);
    int endY = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+1) * stepChangeY);

    int cpX1 = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+0.25) * stepChangeX);
    if((i+1)%2) {
        cpX1 -= horizontalWiggle;
    } else {
        cpX1 += horizontalWiggle;
    }
    int cpY1 = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+0.25) * stepChangeY);

    int cpX2 = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+0.75) * stepChangeX);
    if((i+1)%2) {
        cpX2 -= horizontalWiggle;
    } else {
        cpX2 += horizontalWiggle;
    }
    int cpY2 = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+0.75) * stepChangeY);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, startX, startY);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, cpX1, cpY1, cpX2, cpY2, endX, endY);
}
```

Good luck!